# Handling background network operations in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

Let me just preface this by saying that I'm not entirely familiar with Python, but have plenty of experience with programming in other languages.

I'm working on a tool that allows me to inject packets into a TCP network stream. The idea is that my code acts as a transparent proxy between two network endpoints. I've got the code working such that the proxy works, and I can even parse the packets and automate injection (i.e. detect a particular state and modify / inject packets), but my end goal is to involve user interaction.

What I'm trying to work out is how I can go about having the network stuff run in the background, whilst the command line interface prompts the user for commands. When the command is given, it might perform some kind of injection.

In C# I'd handle this with a background worker task or thread, then have the CLI trigger events, but I'm not familiar with how this kind of design is usually implemented in Python. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're familiar with the pattern of having a background process and triggering events, you could take the same approach in python. Take a look at the [Multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html) to create a background process (Thus avoiding the Global Intepreter Lock issue) and use a Pipe to send messages to the background process to trigger events

Alternatively you could take a look at a package such as [Trellis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Trellis) to take an event driven approach, or perhaps teh Twisted framework. I can't speak for either of these though as I have never used them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Threads is the way to go ( isn't background worker the same thing? ). Something like this:

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading

queue = Queue()

def job():
    while True:
        command = queue.get() # <-- waits until something is in the queue
        # do something with the command

# main thread
t = threading.Thread(target=job)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while True:
    command = raw_input("---> ")
    queue.put(command)
```

Comment: Looks potentially ideal. I'll give this a go and see how it works out.

Comment: And re: your question about background workers in C#... not exactly. A task is *not guaranteed* to run on its own personal thread, but is instead scheduled onto a thread pool. So it might actually end up meaning that your task runs on the same thread as your calling code, if your calling code happens to yield execution immediately after the task is scheduled.

Comment: @Polynomial I see. Well, I'm always confused with MS naming. :)